# Fast way to find number of common items python

Tags: python

I have a large data of 145000 items (a bill of materials) and I want to check the % of shared items between two bill of materials.

Two for loops or other methods always run in similar time periods.

What is the fastest way to do this?

First&secondbill are the lists with components in them:

```
for FKid in FirstBill: 
      for SKid in SecondBill:
            CommonChild = (CommonChild + 1) if FKid == SKid else CommonChild
    return CommonChilds / len(FirstBill)
```

[image]

Comment: You can use sets and set operations.

Comment: no its too big for sets, just use list intersection below

Comment: A common way to find intersections is to use sets. In your case since you just need the count and not a list of common items, `len(set(FirstBill) & set(SecondBill))`.

Comment: One (not the best) way: `len([item for item in FirstBill if item in SecondBill])`.

Comment: @user8426627 A set wouldn't need so much more memory than a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda optimal to use one set

```
# Python program to illustrate the intersection 
# of two lists in most simple way 
def intersection(lst1, lst2): 
    temp = set(lst2) 
    lst3 = [value for value in lst1 if value in temp ] 
    return lst3 

# Driver Code 
lst1 = [4, 9, 1, 17, 11, 26, 28, 54, 69] 
lst2 = [9, 9, 74, 21, 45, 11, 63, 28, 26] 
#print(intersection(lst1, lst2)) 

quantity = len(intersection(lst1, lst2))
```

Comment: How is this better than the current method which also requires 2 loops? I'd argue that the current one is better than this because it doesn't create a new common list, and simply counts the common elements.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this before but saw no significant difference.

Comment: ok, then build no array:
for value in lst1: if value in temp: count +=1 but python is generaly not realy fast, so...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that ids in the bills are unique, a simpler answer would be:

```
percentage = sum([1 for fkid in FirstBill if fkid in SecondBill]) / len(FirstBill) * 100
```

or

```
percentage = len(set(FirstBill).intersection(set(SecondBill))) / len(FirstBill) * 100
```

Comment: I tried something like this too, I now added the list of things Ive tried